# How to handle errors globally in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, alamofire

I have a api where users roles can expire, at which point every request will return a 410 error code.

I'd like a global handler to reset some data, prompt UI to reset, etc.

What's best suited hook into Alamofire?
Currently I have a `RequestInterceptor` and override its `retry` where I inspect the error as

```
if let error = error as? AFError, case 
   .responseValidationFailed(.unacceptableStatusCode(410)) = error {
```

However, the `retry` is called twice, which is not good for my case.

```
responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(code: 410))
responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(code: 410))
```

Is there some other hook I could use, other than handling it manually on a "higher level"? Interceptor seemed to fit very well

Comment: When it retries the second time, you could do `if let afError = error.asAFError, afError.isRequestRetryError { //That's the second time, call super.retry(...); return }`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to simply hook into your response handler or async request. In any API of any complexity you'll want to wrap your Alamofire usage in a convenience layer which configures what you need. However you do that you can see the errors flow through.

```swift
func request(..., completion: (AFDataResponse<T>) -> Void) {
  session...
    .responseDecodable(of: T.self) { response in
      // Perform global behavior.
      completion(response)
    }
}
```

or

```swift
func request(...) async -> AFDataResponse<T> {
  let response = await session...
    .serializingDecodable(T.self)
  // Global error handling
  return response
}
```